# How to display integers instead of floats in a pie chart legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

My code:

```
    ggplot(faixa_vol_op_contagem, aes(x = "", y = num_vol_op, fill = FAIXA_DESENROLA)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
       theme_void()
```

returns this:

[image]

Instead of 1, 1.25 and so on, I just want 1 and 2. How can I do this?

Comment: Please Share a reproducible example. try `dput(faixa_vol_op_contagem)` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: My guess is you are looking for `fill = factor(FAIXA_DESENROLA)` so that you have two colors with two labels. Try changing the first line as above, and adding `scale_fill_manual(name = 'Faixa Desenrola', values = c('red', 'blue'))` to your plot

Comment: ```y=round(num_vol_op, 1)```

Comment: Thank y'all for the answers, just transforming into a factor solved the problem.